# Autocomplete parenthesis around a variable in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete

Consider I have a statement like this in IntelliJ:

```
String spaces = "I have spaces";     
System.out.println(spaces)
```

I want to change the code to :

```
String spaces = "I have spaces";     
System.out.println(StringUtility.removeSpaces(spaces));
```

When I use IntelliJ autocomplete it auto-completes removeSpaces() for me but puts the variable spaces outside the parenthesis.

```
String spaces = "I have spaces";     
System.out.println(StringUtility.removeSpaces()spaces);
```

Any way to make it autocomplete with spaces inside as intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the opening parenthesis <kbd>(</kbd> to complete the auto-completion. You'll end up with:

```
String spaces = "I have spaces";     
System.out.println(StringUtility.removeSpaces(spaces);
```

Then use *Complete Current Statement* <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to fix the closing parenthesis.

Comment: Sorry to reply back to this now. This solution was working but in not working anymore at least when I am using the Scala plugin. Right now when I hit "(" it just adds a "(" besides the word. For eg. consider I start with "test" and enter System.out.prin and select "print" from the auto-complete with "(", it just enter System.out.prin("test". If I do auto-complete with Ctrl+Shift+Enter it enters System.out.print()"test". Probably an issue with keymap. What are the settings etc. that I could use to control this?

Comment: This could be a problem with the Scala plugin. Consider [reporting a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL).